# Combine two overlapping tables of date ranges

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I'm trying to combine two tables with date ranges, in Excel.

I have properties that have certain seasonal pricing, and I have packages that have OTHER seasonal margins, and I need to combine the date brackets for the two.

I can figure out all the margin/pricing stuff in VBA. It's included here because otherwise the data looks identical in certain cases, even when it's not. But I'm having no luck even getting started on combining the dates.

This is the primary table; any date created by joining the two tables/ranges should be included in these dates:

[image: Reg Data]

I need to merge this type of regional data with specific property data:

[image: Base Prop Data]

And when I combine, them, it needs to look something like this:

[image: Combined Data]

I can do this easily dumping data into SQL, but I need something replicable by anyone in the company, from Excel spreadsheets.

I've tried various formula schemes - do this, then that, then this other thing. I've tried doing a cross-join with power query, and then trying to eliminate the dates that I don't want. None of that works.

I knew from the gitgo that it wanted to be done in VBA, and everything else I tried was kinda stalling tactics. The problem is, I can't seem to even wrap my head around the logic required. And I have more than one use-case for this logic.

All property dates need to exist (within a range) in the primary table.
Properties may have dates that don't exist in the primary ranges at all.

Comment: Tried the almighty vlookup already?

Comment: I need more records than the count of the first set and the count of the second set. Brackets are *created* depending on where the sets intersect. That is why there are more records in the last (desired) set than the the first two combined.

Vlookup isn't helpful in this situation.

Comment: To be clear, the number of records in the first set (the regions/margins) will run somewhere from 70 to 100. The number of property records (where the price changes by date) could run 1000 or more.

Comment: 5 minutes is not long enough to type out a coherent answer, so SO just thrashed all of my edits.

Anyway, Vlookup is useful if I had one record in the first set for every one record in the second set OR if we weren't actually creating multiple new date brackets. So a property with two price brackets, overlapping 2 region/margin brackets could create result in seven lines of data. Look at the finished example and compare to the original data, and it will make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are more efficient ways but here is how I would do it using named tables for the data and a range for the output. You should be able to modify it to suit. The logic was a bit more complicated that I thought. Under the code is a screen grab of my test output which matches your table.

```
Option Explicit
Sub TableMerge()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim insert_row As Integer
    Dim prev_FINISH As Date
    Dim Table_1 As ListObject
    Dim Table_2 As ListObject

    insert_row = 2
    prev_FINISH = CDate("01/01/1900")

    Set Table_1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    Set Table_2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2")

    For i = 1 To Table_2.ListRows.Count
        For j = 1 To Table_1.ListRows.Count

        ' assumes the headers are in place, using range L:R for Table3
            If (Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("REG").Index) = Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("REG").Index)) And (Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("Finish").Index) > Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("Start").Index)) And (Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("sTART").Index) < Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("Finish").Index)) Then
                If (prev_FINISH = CDate("01/01/1900") And (Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("Start").Index) <= Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("Finish").Index))) Or (prev_FINISH >= Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("Start").Index)) Or (Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("Finish").Index) >= Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("Start").Index)) Then

                'If (prev_FINISH = CDate("01/01/1900") And (Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("Start").Index) <= Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("Finish").Index)) 'Or (Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("Finish").Index) >= Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("Finish").Index))) Then
                ' add new entry
                    ActiveSheet.Range("L" & insert_row).Value = Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("REG").Index)
                    ActiveSheet.Range("M" & insert_row).Value = Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("Name").Index)
                    ActiveSheet.Range("N" & insert_row).Value = maxoftwo(maxoftwo(Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("Start").Index), Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("Start").Index)), prev_FINISH)
                    ActiveSheet.Range("O" & insert_row).Value = minoftwo(Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("Finish").Index), Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("Finish").Index))
                    ActiveSheet.Range("P" & insert_row).Value = Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("MARG").Index)
                    ActiveSheet.Range("Q" & insert_row).Value = Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("COST").Index)
                    ActiveSheet.Range("R" & insert_row).Formula = "=Q:Q/(1-P:P)"
                    If ActiveSheet.Range("O" & insert_row).Value <> Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("Finish").Index) Then
                        prev_FINISH = ActiveSheet.Range("O" & insert_row).Value
                    Else
                        prev_FINISH = CDate("01/01/1900")
                        j = 1
                        insert_row = insert_row + 1
                        GoTo Next_i
                    End If
                    insert_row = insert_row + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next j
        prev_FINISH = CDate("01/01/1900")
    Next_i:
    Next i
End Sub

Function maxoftwo(date1 As Date, date2 As Date) As Date
    maxoftwo = date1
    If date2 > date1 Then maxoftwo = date2
End Function

Function minoftwo(date1 As Date, date2 As Date) As Date
    minoftwo = date1
    If date2 < date1 Then minoftwo = date2
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out in a bit. (Launched a new website today, kind of crazy, so it may take a little while.) I was working creating a few date arrays and marking them accordingly, and this looks MUCH simpler. I'll let you know if I have questions.

Comment: I found a solution that worked faster/better for me/general data, but this DOES work with the data given, so I upvoted.

Comment: I will be doing that some time in the next few days, though it will be more of a description than actual code.

Answer (score 0):

The original answer from 6-JUL-2017 may work for the above dataset, but will not work if there are values in Table2 with end dates equal to the start date of an associated Table1 record (in that instance, a single day will be omitted from the final table). I believe I have fixed that problem by adding "="'s to the first IF statement. Also noticed that there are two "maxoftwo"s stacked on top of each other when pasting values, not sure why - code seems to work fine with only 1.

I've been searching for help achieving this for a pretty long time, and this topic is the only answer I've found so far. If others notice errors or have a better way to enhance this, please do tell. Thanks

```
    Option Explicit
Sub TableMerge()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim insert_row As Integer
    Dim prev_FINISH As Date
    Dim Table_1 As ListObject
    Dim Table_2 As ListObject

    insert_row = 2
    prev_FINISH = CDate("01/01/1900")

    Set Table_1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    Set Table_2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2")

    For i = 1 To Table_2.ListRows.Count
        For j = 1 To Table_1.ListRows.Count

        ' assumes the headers are in place, using range L:R for Table3
            If (Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("REG").Index) = Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("REG").Index)) And (Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("Finish").Index) >= Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("Start").Index)) And (Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("sTART").Index) <= Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("Finish").Index)) Then
                If (prev_FINISH = CDate("01/01/1900") And (Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("Start").Index) <= Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("Finish").Index))) Or (prev_FINISH >= Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("Start").Index)) Or (Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("Finish").Index) >= Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("Start").Index)) Then

                'If (prev_FINISH = CDate("01/01/1900") And (Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("Start").Index) <= Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("Finish").Index)) 'Or (Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("Finish").Index) >= Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("Finish").Index))) Then
                ' add new entry
                    ActiveSheet.Range("L" & insert_row).Value = Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("REG").Index)
                    ActiveSheet.Range("M" & insert_row).Value = Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("Name").Index)
                    ActiveSheet.Range("N" & insert_row).Value = maxoftwo(Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("Start").Index), Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("Start").Index))
                    ActiveSheet.Range("O" & insert_row).Value = minoftwo(Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("Finish").Index), Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("Finish").Index))
                    ActiveSheet.Range("P" & insert_row).Value = Table_1.DataBodyRange.Cells(j, Table_1.ListColumns("MARG").Index)
                    ActiveSheet.Range("Q" & insert_row).Value = Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("COST").Index)
                    ActiveSheet.Range("R" & insert_row).Formula = "=Q:Q/(1-P:P)"
                    If ActiveSheet.Range("O" & insert_row).Value <> Table_2.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Table_2.ListColumns("Finish").Index) Then
                        prev_FINISH = ActiveSheet.Range("O" & insert_row).Value
                    Else
                        prev_FINISH = CDate("01/01/1900")
                        j = 1
                        insert_row = insert_row + 1
                        GoTo Next_i
                    End If
                    insert_row = insert_row + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next j
        prev_FINISH = CDate("01/01/1900")
    Next_i:
    Next i
End Sub

Function maxoftwo(date1 As Date, date2 As Date) As Date
    maxoftwo = date1
    If date2 > date1 Then maxoftwo = date2
End Function

Function minoftwo(date1 As Date, date2 As Date) As Date
    minoftwo = date1
    If date2 < date1 Then minoftwo = date2
End Function
```